# Concatenate Strings from same column in Trino based on two identifiers

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I would like to concatenate strings from the same column depending on an identifier. For example, given the table:

| Timestamp | ID | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-17 01:51:44 | A | login |
| 2021-04-17 01:58:43 | A | payment |
| 2021-04-17 02:01:32 | B | login |
| 2021-04-17 02:15:44 | A | login |
| 2021-04-17 02:57:44 | A | payment |
| 2021-04-17 02:59:44 | B | login |
| 2021-04-17 03:15:44 | B | payment |
| 2021-04-17 03:27:44 | A | login |
| 2021-04-17 03:31:44 | A | payment |
| 2021-04-17 03:45:44 | B | login |
| 2021-04-17 03:52:44 | B | payment |
| 2021-04-17 04:01:44 | B | payment |
| 2021-04-17 04:23:44 | A | login |

I would like my query to return:

| event_sequence | ID_sequence |
| --- | --- |
| login, payment | A, A |
| login | B |
| login, payment | A, A |
| login, payment | B, B |
| login, payment | A, A |
| login, payment, payment | B, B, B |
| login | A |

I was thinking of self referencing the column and use the lag function to check if the two identifiers are the same, like:

```
select case when ID = lag(ID,1) over (partition by ID order by datetime asc) 
       then event_type || ',' || lag(event_sequence, 1) over (partition by ID order by datetime asc)
       as event_sequence,
       case case when ID = lag(ID,1) over (partition by ID order by datetime asc) 
       then ID || ',' || lag(ID_sequence, 1) over (partition by ID order by datetime asc)
       as ID_sequence
from table
```

but I don't think self referencing is supported. could a CTE maybe help me getting it?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would suggest aggregating using arrays, rather than strings.  To identify the groups, use a difference of row numbers.  Then aggregate:

```
select id,
       array_agg(event_type order by timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by timestamp) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by id, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

I'm not sure if id sequence is needed, but you can throw in `array_agg(id)` if you want to see it duplicated as well.  And you can easily convert the array to a string using `array_join()`, if you prefer a string.